# Increase width and heigth of gnuplot output

Tags: height, width, gnuplot

I've to plot 180000 points into a single EPS file.
With standards gnuplot output dimensions points are too close each other and that's makes them indistinguible. Is there any way to increase the image width and height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
set terminal epscairo enhanced color size 100in,100in font "Arial,100"
```

This will make (for example) an .eps 100 inches by 100 inches with a large font.  You can type

```
help terminal pdfcairo
```

at the gnuplot command line for more information.

Comment: Is there any way to set size with pixels? And to use this with png output?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is pretty much the same: `set terminal pngcairo size 10000,10000 font "Arial,100"`... something like that.  You can get more information with the command `help set XXX`, where XXX is some setting for the `set` command.

Comment: Equivalent for svg images: `set terminal svg size 800,600 font "DejaVu Sans,16"`